# How to get Firestore "has sync to the cloud" status for a specific collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the **sync status** for a document with multiple child collections in Firestore.

The app supports both online and offline. Before the user closes a screen I want to check whether all data in the document has **synced to the cloud**.

What I have tried currently is the `hasPendingWrites` attribute. But I always get `false`.

```
db.collection("cities").doc(city.id).onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=> {
  console.log(querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites);
});
```

Edit - I'm updating documents in nested collections of the city. Can it be the issue?

My collection structure

```
cities document (which I'm listening to the sync status)
├─── leaders collection (which I'm updating)
├─── fleet collection (which I'm updating)
├─── roads collection (which I'm updating)
├─── maps collection (which I'm updating)
```

Comment: Have you checked if `hasPendingWrites` behaves as it should when the app is offline? You could test with the [snippet from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).

Comment: Hi @ErnestoC, I'm updating documents in nested collections of cities. Can it be the issue?

Comment: Since you are updating in nested collections. If the nested collections have the same name (let's call it innercities). you can try `db.collectionGroup("innercities")...`

Comment: Hi @ObumunemeNwabude, I updated the document structure. With that I don't think collectionGroup won't work

Comment: so try and lets see if it will work. use these inner collections (leaders, fleet, roads, maps) with collectionGroup. Did the problem get solved?

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude these collections have documents with different attributes. I'm thinking about how these collections can be grouped?

Comment: collectionGroup is a special function to permit you to access collections from their names irrespective of where they are. The advantage is it permits you to access subcollections across various documents. So you can have collectionGroup('leaders') instead of collection('leaders') and it is to it that you will attach the snapshot listener of hasPendingWrites. And you would have to do the same for the other subcollections like fleet, roads, and maps. this might increase read/write cost for documents in Firebase when your produce scales.

Comment: Thanks @ObumunemeNwabude. I got it now. I didn't think it in the cost respective. Is there any idea of the cost? I have 4 listeners now. In a user session, I estimate there will be around 200 listens for listeners. I don't think I can pay when it scales. Is there any alternate way to get any pending writes to the cloud? I don't need to listen though. If I can get a value if all data has synced to the database or not that'll be enough.

Comment: For an alternate way of getting pending writes, maybe we will first have to understand the reason for trying to sync before the website closes in the first place. What do you want to achieve? Then for the cost, well I don't know your current database structure in its full entirety, but I will say that that structure can be improved to reduce cost. And if you feel its optimum then you are fine, you should either monetize enough by the time app scales or maybe Firestore is not the best database for your application. Firestore is not very expensive by the way...

Comment: The charge is about $0.1 (on average) per extra 100k reads above the free 50k daily quota reads. So it won't be much and you will not quickly get to this point on the other hand

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude the reason for the sync is if the user tries to uninstall the app, all the data will be lost. So I want to sync before the app closes. Btw this is a mobile app.

Comment: It's getting clearer. For mobile app uninstall, the thing is the feature is hard to implement. What if the user is trying to uninstall when they are not connected to the internet? Sync can't take place and data will be lost. I think you should have parts of the UI that let the user know the importance of their internet connection, hope you understand. Also, I assumed it was a website because the code snippet you initially shared resembles what JavaScript has.

Comment: Thanks, @ObumunemeNwabude. I'll try to implement it in that way. In the logout, I'll perform the "waitForPendingWrites" function if the internet connectivity is there.

Comment: Great, syncing on logout is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm happy to give the bounty reward to you. I think I can't give it to you unless you add this as an answer.

Comment: Wow, thannks, that's very kind, okay, let me compose an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Use collectionGroup

[collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group) is a special function to permit you to access collections from their names irrespective of where they are.

The advantage is it permits you to access subcollections across various documents. So you can have `collectionGroup('leaders')` instead of collection('leaders') and it is to it that you will attach the snapshot listener of hasPendingWrites. And you would have to do the same for the other subcollections like 'fleet', 'roads', and 'maps'.

Note that this might unnecessarily increase read/write costs for documents in Firebase when your produce scales.

#### Solution 2: The UI (Recommended)

Have parts of the UI that let the user know the importance of their internet connection. Maybe preventing access entirely, showing some vector or banner if the user is not having good internet.

This solution is better because detecting sync status on your own would be an overkill. It's not just a Firebase thing. Even if you were implementing custom WebSockets by yourself. Besides Firebase has auto-syncing properties already, which is the `.onSnapshot()` method itself.

Also, you can't tell if the user is trying to uninstall a mobile app when they are not connected to the internet? Sync can't take place and data will be lost. So it is best to make them feel that the product is more of online stuff. Besides, almost everything is online today.